# How to make a dynamic Relationship with versioning in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, relationship, versioning

I don't really know how to name what I'm trying to do, so I better explain it with a concrete case.

I have tree tables : *Product*, *ProductionReport* and *CommercialReference*.

A *CommercialReference* have one *Product* and a *Product* can have multiple *CommercialReference*. Also, a *ProductionReport* have one *Product* and a *Product* can be in multiple *ProductionReport*.

My problem is that I want to do some versioning on my *Product*. So we can have "Gold Wheat v1, v2, etc...". My *CommercialReference* should **only point out the "current active" version of my *Product*** (with an ActiveVersion bit by example), but the *ProductionReport* should only point the active *Product* **at the moment of the production**.

How can I make relationship between *ProductionReport* and *Product* and between *CommercialReference* and *Product* with these conditions ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your answers.

Note : My *Product* table have a double primary key (Id, Version) so I don't have problem to make a relationship with the *ProductionReport* table but, of course, it's not what I want to do with my *CommercialReference* table.
Basically, what I want to do is :
[Table's description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycpFz.png)

Comment: Rather than versions, why not use a temporal table? Then you have a (version) history of the product in the history table, but only one live value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this idea ! I didn't know that thing even existed.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an entity.  You need something like Product, and ProductVersion.  So that you have a table with PK of just ProductID to use for CommercialReference, whereas ProductionReport references ProductVersion.